# Create foreign key to table that doesn't exist in postgres

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I've also asked this question in DBA exchange, but not sure if that is the right place.

I'm trying to put together a solution where I have a bunch of script files that contain my schema creation. Something similar to Visual Studio's SQL Project, but for Postgres.

My problem is that the files won't necessarily be read in the correct order, for instance the first file/script/table read has a dependency on the 2nd file/script/table.

I was hoping there was some way I could disable the check to see if the referred table/column does exist, creating all the tables, and then re-enabling the check.

I'm running 9.2.24

My 2nd solution would be to order the files in such a way that it does only create a table when the dependencies already exist, but my above mention method would be preferred.

Comment: You'll have to create the referenced table before the foreign key referencing it.

Comment: Could you use something like flyway or one of the other migration software managers to make sure your scripts are executed in the proper order?

Comment: If there is a circular dependency, there is no proper order possible.

Comment: @wildplasser there's no circular dependency

Comment: @jeremy never heard about flyway before, will check it out thanks!

Comment: @WynDiesel In that case, the graph is a DAG, and you can find a partial order.

Comment: @wildplasser. Thanks for that! I had this concept in mind, but didn't know what the name was for it.